Electron window not appearing
Project consists of react + node.js 16.20.2 + sqlite + electron 33.0.2. Electron window doesn't appear after running npm run electron-start.
This is my script section in my root package.json.
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run electron-start",
    "start-client": "cd client && BROWSER=none npm start ",
    "start-server": "cd server && node server.js",
    "electron-start": "concurrently \"npm run start-server\" \"npm run start-client\" && wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .",
    "build-electron": "electron-builder"
  }

Electron.js:
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const { spawn } = require("child_process");
const path = require("path");

let mainWindow;
let reactProcess;

function createWindow() {
  console.log("Creating Electron window...");
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
    },
  });

  // Load the React app
  mainWindow
    .loadURL("http://localhost:3000")
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Loaded React app in Electron window.");
      mainWindow.webContents.on("did-finish-load", () => {
        console.log(`Current URL: ${mainWindow.webContents.getURL()}`);
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error("Failed to load URL in Electron window:", err);
    });

  reactProcess.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
    console.log(`React: ${data}`);
  });

  reactProcess.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
    console.error(`React error: ${data}`);
  });

  mainWindow.on("closed", () => {
    if (reactProcess) {
      reactProcess.kill("SIGINT");
    }
    mainWindow = null;
  });
}

app.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("Electron app is ready");
  createWindow();
});

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});
app.on("activate", () => {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});


This is the output I get in my console:
[0] 
[0] > tournamentbracket@1.0.0 start-server
[0] > cd server && node server.js
[0] 
[1] 
[1] > tournamentbracket@1.0.0 start-client
[1] > cd client && BROWSER=none npm start
[1] 
[0] Server is running on http://localhost:5000
[0] Connected to the tournament database.
[0] Users table created.
[0] Tournaments table created.
[0] Matches table created.
[0] Brackets table created.
[1] 
[1] > client@0.1.0 start
[1] > react-scripts start
[1] 
[1] (node:12836) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_AFTER_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onAfterSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
[1] (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
[1] (node:12836) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_BEFORE_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onBeforeSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
[1] Starting the development server...
[1] 
[1] Compiled successfully!
[1] 
[1] You can now view client in the browser.
[1] 
[1]   Local:            http://localhost:3000
[1]   On Your Network:  http://192.168.1.103:3000
[1] 
[1] Note that the development build is not optimized.
[1] To create a production build, use npm run build.
[1] 
[1] webpack compiled successfully

It isn't even reaching the electron.js file to create the window.
Any ideas what is happening?

&& waits for the previous command to terminate before executing the next one. may be try something like "electron-start": "concurrently \"npm run start-server\" \"npm run start-client\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000\" \"electron .\""

@PrerakSola Thank you for your comment. Initially, when I started using the concurrently annotation, it was to solve the issue of the reactapp not loading before the electron window. Your solution does make the window appear again, but I'm forced to refresh the page to get the reactapp to appear.
